# Precedence and meaning of the ! operator in PHP

Tags: php, operator-keyword

In PHP doc it is said that the operator ! has higher precedence than any other logical or any comparison operators.

I created 3 conditions:

```
$x = 4; $y = -12; 

if(!$x >= 0 AND !$y >= 0)){echo '1/ Validated';}
if(!($x >= 0) AND !($y >= 0)){echo '2/Validated';}
if(!($x >= 0 AND $y >= 0)){echo '3/Validated';}
```

The first if echoes validated, the second one doesn't and the third do.

I just don't understand why the first if echoes validated. To my understanding, here the comparisons $x >= 0 and $y >=0 are evaluated (true and false to start with) and THEN the result is reversed which makes it false and true and we FINALLY have if(false AND true) and the code inside the if should not be executed.

I suppose I'm mistaking over the ability of the "!" operator or on the precedence but I can't understand where.

Can someone clarify please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` has higher precedence than `>=`, so this:

```
if(!$x >= 0 AND !$y >= 0)
```

Is evaluated like this:

```
if(((!$x) >= 0) AND ((!$y) >= 0))
```

I.e., `!$x` is evaluated *before* the `>=`.

So, we have:

- `$x = 4`
- `!$x` evaluates to false (4 evaluated as a bool is true, then invert it)
- `(!$x) >= 0` evaluates to true (false from previous step evaluated as int is 0)
- `$y = -12`
- `!$y` evaluates to false (-12 evaluated as a bool is true, then invert it)
- `(!$y) >= 0` evaluates to true (false from previous step evaluated as int is 0)
- `!$x >= 0 AND !$y >= 0` evaluates to `true AND true`, which is true

Comment: "so (!$x) >= 0 is true." the expression actually runs as `(!4) >= 0` because `$x = 4`... `(!4) = false` and  `(false >= 0)` = true because false and 0 are the same in PHP.

Comment: Oh ok I got it! Thanks for your answer. I'll accept it as soon as I stackoverflow let me. Thanks again!

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's the same as what I said, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Also @PierreGiraud take a look into [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) which uses automatic type conversion.. it has a section " Converting to boolean
Converting to integer
Converting to float
Converting to string
Converting to array
Converting to object
Converting to resource " which you can check how PHP is going to auto cast.

Comment: Yeah I meant yours @Alex Howansky since you were the first to reply. Sorry I'm not using that website often so I replied where I could :)

Comment: "That's the same as what I said, isn't it? Am I missing something?" No i don't think you missed something.. So it seams indeed you said the same i said.. i explained in more detail so it was more easy to follow.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Gotcha, thanks, I'll edit my answer a bit to clarify.